# user created Functions in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i'm trying to simplify some sql..
right now im doing the following as a example

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 test_table 
WHERE
 test_table.apples in 
  ( 
   SELECT 
    condition 
   FROM 
    lookup_table
   WHERE 
    lookup_table.condition1="blah1"
   AND
    lookup_table.condition2="blah2"
   AND
    lookup_table.condition3="blah3"
  )
```

what i'm looking to do is replace my sub query with a function with parameters
for example

```
lookup('parameter1','paramater2','paramiter3')..
```

im unsure what datatype i need to return.. a varray.. a table..
i just want this function to simulate the subquery.
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Rather than creating functions, have you considered views, or a [subquery factoring clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2161315)? Functions can have undesirable performance impacts, whereas views and CTE's are readily evaluated by the optimizer.

Comment: You also avoid context switching between the SQL and PL/SQL engines.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a type like this:

```
create type mytabtype is table of varchar2(100);
```

Then your function can return that type and you would use it like this:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 test_table 
WHERE
 test_table.apples in (SELECT column_value 
                       FROM TABLE(lookup('parameter1','paramater2','paramiter3'));
```